# Creating Page Elements Only If JSON Data is Present

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, angularjs

When I receive JSON data from the server, I customize the page depending on the data I get from JSON. The problem is, if the page is highly customized I will need an `if` statement for every element that needs creating in HTML.

The question is, is there another way besides checking every single variable in AngularJS? Example JSON data:

```
{
    user_logged_in: 'yes', 
    user_custom_background: 'no', 
    user_likes_page: 'yes'
}
```

In AngularJS I will need an `if` statement checking each JSON variable in order to decide if I should display something on the page or not, so the number of `if`s can become exponential.

**Edit**
By Exponential I mean that the page has a lot of elements to be created depending on user data from the database, retrieved as JSON, each one requiring its own `if` statement.

The Rending logic would be, pseudo code:

```
if user_logged_in: 'yes' then show black `div`
if user_custom_background: 'yes' then change background color 
if user_likes_page: 'yes' then display message
```

The number of IFs would be HUGE for a complex web app.

Comment: Can you show us your render logic? This doesn't seem exponential to me, just linear.

Comment: Not an answer, but it would be easier for you to store those values as boolean (true/false) instead of strings. Then you can  do `if(user_logged_in)` etc.

Comment: @Doctus yes what I provided what just some sort of pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using AngularJS, you should be able to assign the JSON data from the server to a scope variable within your controller as follows:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/server/data',
}).success(function(response) {
    $scope.serverResponse = response;
});
```

For testing purposes, I would skip the async call and just use the object in your question to set `serverResponse` (*Note that I followed the suggestion from @Doctus to use booleans.*):

```
$scope.serverResponse = {
    user_logged_in: true, 
    user_custom_background: false, 
    user_likes_page: true
};
```

The rest would involve HTML markup changes.  Based on your pseudo code, I assume the following changes need to be done:

```
<div id="black" ng-show="serverResponse.user_logged_in">Logged In</div>
<div id="background" ng-style="{'background-color': ( serverResponse.user_custom_background ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00')}">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="message" ng-show="serverResponse.user_likes_page">Message</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle that show this in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/sy0q263n/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for reply. Although that does simplify using the ng-if, I am sure internally there are the same amount of if statements running to check for the variables to be set or not, which is what I wanted to avoid, using so many conditionals. I guess there is no other way to do this except checking for every variable.

Comment: @user3704920 If those variables are logically related, you could probably link them up as input to a state machine, and the state machine would set attributes on your elements.  Say you associate a bit flag to each property and XOR them all, you would get a number which maps to a state.  user_logged_in (1), user_custom_background (2) and user_likes_page (4) set to true false true would generate a 5, which your code knows as show black div and display message.  The only `if` here would be in your switch statement, if you don't count jQuery selector internals.